# why the two different approaches of create postgres docker instance differ

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Why wouldn't the following two situations be equivalent?
approach 1:
i have docker-compose.xml

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

apporach 2:
in  docker-compose.xml

```
services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

in Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:15
```

The first one works. But in the second approach, I got errors

```
2024-02-24 20:50:07 2024-02-25 04:50:07.584 UTC [1] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_messages": "en_US.utf8"
2024-02-24 20:50:07 2024-02-25 04:50:07.584 UTC [1] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_monetary": "en_US.utf8"
2024-02-24 20:50:07 2024-02-25 04:50:07.584 UTC [1] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_numeric": "en_US.utf8"
2024-02-24 20:50:07 2024-02-25 04:50:07.584 UTC [1] LOG:  invalid value for parameter "lc_time": "en_US.utf8"
2024-02-24 20:50:07 2024-02-25 04:50:07.584 UTC [1] FATAL:  configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf" contains errors
2024-02-24 20:47:25 
2024-02-24 20:47:25 PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
```

Because I don't see any directory at the location `/var/lib/postgresql/data`

Can you please let me know what is going on? Am I understanding the base image wrong?

Comment: Was there ever a point where you had both `image:` and `build:` in the file at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

### I tried to recreate the error and got a different log output

```bash
Attaching to db-1
db-1  |
db-1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db-1  |
db-1  | 2024-02-25 05:20:50.394 UTC [1] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
db-1  | 2024-02-25 05:20:50.394 UTC [1] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 16, which is not compatible with this version 15.6 (Debian 15.6-1.pgdg120+2).
db-1 exited with code 0
```

### This Dockerfile setup works for me

`docker-compose.build.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: yourdbname
      POSTGRES_USER: youruser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: yourpassword
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  db_data:
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM postgres:16
```

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.build.yml up --build --remove-orphans`

### The same error occurred when trying to run `postgres:15` using the image, but `16` again solves that error

`docker-compose.image.yml`

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:16
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: yourdbname
      POSTGRES_USER: youruser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: yourpassword
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  db_data:
```

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.image.yml up --build --remove-orphans`

### Conclusion

The lack of compatibility points to an outdated docker-compose version or some change that occurred between postgres images 15 and 16